# How to display a blob image in Android?

Tags: android, imageview

I want to display an image which is saved into database in blob form on my Android. I am using ImageView as image container. Please suggest me something soon.

Regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically there are two options:

1. Buffer read from BLOB wrap in InputStream so you will have InputStream which will point to BLOB data
2. Save BLOB data to temporary file open it as FileInputStream - so in the end you'll again have stream over image data

in both cases you can easily convert InputStream to bitmat data in a way:

```
InputStream is; //stream pointing to your blob or file
//...
imageView=new ImageView(this);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
```

Comment: Thanks Barmaley, I tried the 2nd option. As i am recieving this data through a web service, i am getting class cast exception whrn i am assigning my response object property to InputStream as:                                                      InputStream is=(InputStream) response.getProperty(7);               what to do in that case