# getting blob data and using imageView as its container

Tags: android, blob

I have an sqlite database that has a blob column with blob data. I have tried the following but it is not showing anything. Please advice:

```
public Cursor getHiddenImages()
    {
        dbConnection connection=new dbConnection(getApplicationContext());
        SQLiteDatabase db=connection.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor=db.query(dbConnection.TABLE_IMAGES,null, null, null, null, null, null);
        return cursor;
    }
        cursor=getHiddenImages();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        byte[]mybyteArray=cursor.getBlob(cursor.getColumnIndex(dbConnection.IMAGE_DATA));
        Bitmap theImage=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(mybyteArray, 0, mybyteArray.length);
        imageview.setImageBitmap(theImage);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and also check the below links,

```
    Buffer = Cursor1.GetBlob("Image")
    Dim Canvas1 As Canvas
    Canvas1.Initialize(ImageView1)
    Dim IN As InputStream
    IN.InitializeFromBytesArray(Buffer,0,Buffer.Length)
    IN.Close
    Msgbox(buffer.Length,"Image lenght")
    Msgbox(In.BytesAvailable,"available")
    Canvas1.Bitmap.Initialize2(IN)
    ImageView1.Bitmap = Canvas1.Bitmap
```

Check out these links u can solve ur prob.
[Assignin blob to imageview](http://www.android50.com/Topic/view/id-6701)
[display image from blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028751/how-to-display-image-from-blob-data-in-android-sqlite)
[Blob to imageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591519/how-to-display-a-blob-image-in-android)

Comment: Thanx for your answer but I am using Android not VB