# Load BLOB to Gallery android

Tags: java, android, mysql

I would like to read a Blob of my MySQL database
This "Array" BLOB would be placed in a "Gallery".

**Code to read BLOB from the database:**

```
while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("id");
            String description = rs.getString("description");
            Blob image = (Blob) rs.getBlob("img");

            Material m = new Material(id, description,image);
            listaMaterial.add(m);
}
```

Como eu faço para colocar várias BLOB em uma Gallery, qual transformação devo fazer?

Comment: What problem are you facing ?
P.S> You can use Base64 encoded strings for storing images instead of blob

Comment: I do not have a foundation of how to do it

Comment: check my answer, hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store images in base64 format - 
To Encode :

```
Bitmap clickedPhoto;
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
clickedPhoto.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
String strData = Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

You can store this `strData` as a varchar/text in your database

To Decode:

```
byte[] arrPhoto = Base64.decode(strData, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(arrPhoto, 0, arrPhoto.length);
```

Get `strData` by using getString() from your ResultSet and then decode it to a Bitmap to use in your application.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Where do I put the variable BLOB?

Comment: You dont need to use blob objects, you can use simple String classes. In the above example strData holds the string representation of the bitmap data which you can store/decode.  Check this link, might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591519/how-to-display-a-blob-image-in-android

Comment: In my table within the database is of type BLOB, as I read this picture in java then?

Comment: Aakash "Yes, but how I can convert a blob to the Input stream? That part is omitted"

Comment: Use Blob.getBinaryStream() to get an InputStream

Comment: And to put Imageview in Gallery?

Comment: You will have to create an adapter class for that
http://learnandroideasily.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-gallery-view-example.html