# using Images from sqlLite Blob and using them in setImageResource in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I'm making a app project to bring up a sqlite database with and Id, 2 different string columns and 1 blob, Im having trouble figuring out how to output the blob into a `byte[]` so it can be used by `setImageResource`

I've tried:

```
Card chat = (Card) spinner.getAdapter().getItem(position);
byte[] tvImg = activity.findViewById(R.id.reviewing_card);
        tvImg.setImageResource(chat.getCardImg());
```

but on the setImageResource I get `"Cannot resolve method 'setImageResource(byte[])'`

Any input would be great, thank you.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40838429/15298643) is pretty much everything that you need to do.

Comment: [Another options here too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591519/how-to-display-a-blob-image-in-android)